# Do I need to learn iOS 6 development before I learn iOS 7?

Tags: ios6, ios7

I'm a newbie developer, I have no experience with iOS 6 development and I wish to code and develop iOS 7 apps using XCode. Will I be facing any difficulties if I directly start learning iOS 7 development?

Comment: Well you should better invest your time studying `OOP` concepts and general programming concepts. They any programing language is just about getting to know the framework. Start with the basic and work you way up. And there isn't that much different between iOS 7 and 6, just some UI changes which are well documented.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can start from iOS7 keeping in mind that if you need to deploy on lower targets some functionalities could be not applicable. 
Before Cocoa Touch (the set of iOS Frameworks) you should start to learn Objective-C and OOP concepts. Designing patterns comprehension will be really useful for get the most from Cocoa Touch.

Answer (score 0):

Start with what Apple tells you to start with, and that is [Start Developing iOS Apps Today](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/index.html) from the [Apple Developers Site](https://developer.apple.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can start with iOs 7 no problem, there is no technical reason to learn iOs 6. You may however have some problems learning it from books, because they are not updated yet. I give some lessons on this subject and use iOs programming from the big nerd ranch. This book is not updated yet, and in classes I have to adapt some examples. 
Another thing will be deployment. Do you want to support iOs 6? I would target only iOs 7 or more. But it depends on your target audience.